# R dist: calculating distance of few to many

Tags: r, distance

Say you have some participants and control in a given experiment that are evaluated in three characteristics, something like this:

```
part_A <- c(3, 5, 4)
part_B <- c(12, 15, 18)
part_C <- c(50, 40, 45)

ctrl_1 <- c(4, 5, 5)
ctrl_2 <- c(1, 0, 4)
ctrl_3 <- c(13, 16, 17)
ctrl_4 <- c(28, 30, 35)
ctrl_5 <- c(51, 43, 44)
```

I want to find for each participant which control case is the closest match.

If I used the `dist()` function, I could get it, but it would take a lot of time also calculating the distances between controls, which is useless to me (and in the real data, there are 1000 times more control cases than participant cases).

Is there a way to ask for the distances between each of *these* elements to each of *those* elements? And something that work for very large data sets?

In the example above, the result I want is:

```
  Participant Closest_Ctrl
1      part_A       ctrl_1
2      part_B       ctrl_3
3      part_C       ctrl_5
```

Comment: You can do this with the `pdist` function from the `pdist` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert input to data frames

```
parts <- do.call(data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "part_[A-C]")))
ctrl <- do.call(data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "ctrl_[1-5]")))
```

Generate output

```
# calculate distances
dists <- outer(parts, ctrl, Vectorize(function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))))

# generate output by calculating column with min value (max negative value)
data.frame(Participant = names(parts), 
           Closest_Ctrl = names(ctrl)[max.col(-dists)])

#   Participant Closest_Ctrl
# 1      part_A       ctrl_1
# 2      part_B       ctrl_3
# 3      part_C       ctrl_5
```

Benchmark

```
parts <- do.call(data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "part_[A-C]")))
ctrl <- do.call(data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "ctrl_[1-5]")))
parts <- do.call(cbind, replicate(100, parts, simplify = F))
ctrl <- do.call(cbind, replicate(100, ctrl, simplify = F))

r1 <- f1()
r2 <- f2()

all.equal(r1 %>% lapply(as.factor) %>% setNames(1:2), 
          r2[2:1] %>% lapply(as.factor) %>% setNames(1:2))
# [1] TRUE


f1 <- function(x){
  dists <- outer(parts, ctrl, Vectorize(function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))))
  # generate output by calculating column with min value (max negative value)
  data.frame(Participant = names(parts), 
             Closest_Ctrl = names(ctrl)[max.col(-dists)])
}

f2 <- function(x){
  res <- vapply(parts, function(x)  colnames(ctrl)[which.min(sqrt(colSums(x - ctrl)^2))], 
            FUN.VALUE = character(1))

  stack(res)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times = 5)        
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  f1()   305.7324   314.8356   435.3961   324.6116   461.4788   770.3221     5
#  f2() 12359.6995 12831.7995 13567.8296 13616.5216 14244.0836 14787.0438     5
```

Benchmark 2

```
parts <- do.call(data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "part_[A-C]")))
ctrl <- do.call(data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "ctrl_[1-5]")))
parts <- do.call(cbind, replicate(10, parts, simplify = F))
ctrl <- do.call(cbind, replicate(10*1000, ctrl, simplify = F))

r1 <- f1()
r2 <- f2()

all.equal(r1 %>% lapply(as.factor) %>% setNames(1:2), 
          r2[2:1] %>% lapply(as.factor) %>% setNames(1:2))
# [1] TRUE


f1 <- function(x){
  dists <- outer(parts, ctrl, Vectorize(function(x, y) sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))))
  # generate output by calculating column with min value (max negative value)
  data.frame(Participant = names(parts), 
             Closest_Ctrl = names(ctrl)[max.col(-dists)])
}

f2 <- function(x){
  res <- vapply(parts, function(x)  colnames(ctrl)[which.min(sqrt(colSums(x - ctrl)^2))], 
            FUN.VALUE = character(1))

  stack(res)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), times = 5)        
# Unit: seconds
#  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#  f1()   3.450176   4.211997   4.493805   4.339818   5.154191   5.312844     5
#  f2() 119.120484 124.280423 132.637003 130.858727 131.148630 157.776749     5
```

Comment: Benchmarks based on such small n are misleading. There should be a factor of 1000 between parts n and controls n.

Comment: This solution works great, but how could you change it such that instead of each column of the df being a participant, every row of the df is a participant?

Comment: I would personally use data.table::transpose to create a new participant data frame with the rows as columns. In base you could use the t function and then convert back to data frame (t converts to matrix)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that should be sufficiently fast for a not-too-big number of participants:

```
ctrl <- do.call(cbind, mget(ls(pattern = "ctrl_\\d+")))

dat <- mget(ls(pattern = "part_[[:upper:]+]"))

res <- vapply(dat, function(x)  colnames(ctrl)[which.min(sqrt(colSums(x - ctrl)^2))], 
                FUN.VALUE = character(1))

stack(res)
#  values    ind
#1 ctrl_1 part_A
#2 ctrl_3 part_B
#3 ctrl_5 part_C
```

If this is too slow I would quickly code it in Rcpp.